# synthetic division with $i$ in divisor

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, divisibility

I divided $x^3-4x^2+4x-16$ by $-2i$ using synthetic division and got a remainder of $-8i-8$. Is that right? I'm not sure I'm doing this right.

Comment: Are you dividing by $x-2i$?

Comment: No. From what I understand of the division rules if it was in the form with the x it would be changed to 2i instead of -2i. It's just -2i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
Let
$$p(x)=x^3-4x^2+4x-16$$
Evaluate $p(\alpha)$ that will be reminder when $p(x)$ is divided by $x-\alpha$

But we have $$p(x)=x^3-4x^2+4x-16=(x-4)(x^2+4)=(x-4)(x+2i)(x-2i)$$ what can you conclude from this?

See [Factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) and [Polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)